# How to add an Image to ShowcaseView library

Tags: android, showcaseview

I want to add a picture maybe an ImageView on top of showcaseView like in this example pic. I've researched regarding this thing but found nothing. I know this is possible , I've seen it on showcaseview's example on playstore. picture below: [image: ShowcaseView sample application]

What I really want to do is this. The library is not well documented. How can I achieve this?

[image]

Comment: this library is on Github, so why don't you askk an authore, by creating new issue on this project page